# Adding New node to NDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I have a server which running Management_node, data_node and mysql-server running whose IP is 10.19.95.36
There were running with one more node whose IP is 10.19.95.37 but the second server was off now.
So just one node is running and it's config.ini is below;

```
[NDBD DEFAULT]
NoOfReplicas=2
DataDir=/IGKDBDATA/mysql/
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=2000000
MaxNoOfLocalOperations=2200000
#MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions=120000
MaxNoOfAttributes=200000
LockPagesInMainMemory=1
DataMemory=8G
IndexMemory=2G
#ODirect=1

NoOfFragmentLogFiles=400
FragmentLogFileSize=128M
RedoBuffer=32M

[MYSQLD DEFAULT]
[NDB_MGMD DEFAULT]
[TCP DEFAULT]
#Yonetim Nodu
[NDB_MGMD]
NodeId=1
HostName=10.19.95.36
#Yonetim Node IP adresi
#Depolama Nodlari]
[NDBD]
NodeId=2
HostName=10.19.95.36
# Depolama Node -1 IPsi
DataDir=/IGKDBDATA/mysql/
[NDBD]
NodeId=3
HostName=10.19.95.37
#Depolama Node -2 IPsi
DataDir=/IGKDBDATA/mysql/

#clients of the cluster

[MYSQLD]
NodeId=4
HostName=10.19.95.36
BatchByteSize=1M
BatchSize=20
MaxScanBatchSize=16M


[MYSQLD]
NodeId=5
HostName=10.19.95.37
BatchByteSize=1M
BatchSize=20
MaxScanBatchSize=16M
```

Also my.cnf of 10.19.95.36 is below;

```
[mysqld]
user=root
#datadir=/IGKDBDATA/mysql/
ndbcluster
ndb-connectstring='host=10.19.95.36'
log = /var/log/mysqld.log
# Yonetim nodunun ip adresi
[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring='host=10.19.95.36'    # Yonetim nodunun ip adresi
```

Now I have new server, and I want to replace this server with 10.19.35.37.
By the way running 10.19.95.36 server version is Redhat 5.5 and 10.131.3.80 new server version is Redhat 7.5

How can I proceed ? What should I do to add this new server to the cluster ?
Actually I searched about ndb cluster but I couldn't get much information.

Should I setup new mysql server and mysql-cluster rpm's ?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therfore it is off topic here on SO. The dba sister site of SO can help you with configuring your database servers!

Comment: Okay thank you, but i could get an answer about my db configurations before